# Extract elements from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm completely new to javascript, so bear with me!

I have a function that has variables passed into it, see below:

```
function.getDestination(
    {
      destinations: [theFirstDestination, theSecondDestination],
    }
```

I can pass as many variables in as I like by explicitly defining them. I also have an array that holds the values I want to pass in, `destinationArray`. Again, I can pass these variables in by explicitly calling them from the array:

```
function.getDestination(
    {
      destinations: [destinationArray[0], destinationArray[1],
    }
```

What I want to do is loop through the entire array and pass every variable into the function: is there a simpler way to do this rather than manually typing every index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do `destinations: destinationArray` if you like, however changes on one side will affect the other. If you want a completely independent copy:

```
destinations: destinationArray.slice(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't pass them correctly. I should also note the varibles on pass if they are enclosed in square brackets, does this effect anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is copy the array into `destinations`. In that case, just use:

```
{
     destinations: destinationArray.slice(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is untested (can't now) but should work..

```
function getDestination(param) {
    for(var i=0;i<param.destinations.length;i++) {

        // do something with i (the number)
        // or with param.destinations[i] (the value)

        console.log(i+": "+param.destinations[i]);
    }
}
```

While this will work with an object too

```
function getDestination(param) {
    for(var it in param.destinations) if(param.destinations.hasOwnProperty(it)) {

        // do something with it (the number or key)
        // or with param.destinations[it] (the value)

        console.log(it+": "+param.destinations[it]);
    }
}
```

And you call one of them like this:

```
getDestination({destinations: [theFirstDestination, theSecondDestination]});
```